# Using decision within a java delegate

Tags: camunda

I am trying to evaluate a decision inside a camunda java delegate that I created. Following is the code that I am using. Upon executing the delegate( which runs fine without the DMN part), I get an error stating:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/odysseus/el/util/SimpleContext"`

I am using gradle and have added the following to my .build :
       `compile 'org.camunda.bpm.dmn:camunda-engine-dmn' ,
        'org.camunda.bpm.dmn:camunda-engine-feel-juel:7.5.0-alpha2' ,
        'de.odysseus.juel:juel-spi:2.2.7',
        'de.odysseus.juel:juel-api:2.2.7' ,
        'de.odysseus.juel:juel-impl:2.2.7'`

Any suggestion how can I fix this error up? Thanks.

**DMN Code:**

```
DmnEngine dmnEngine = DmnEngineConfiguration.createDefaultDmnEngineConfiguration().buildEngine();

// read the DMN XML file as input stream
InputStream inputStream = CheckDatafileExistsExecutor.class.getResourceAsStream("decision1.xml");

// parse the DMN decision from the input stream
DmnDecision decision = dmnEngine.parseDecision("Decision_13nychf", inputStream);

//accessing the input variables
VariableMap variables = Variables.fromMap((Map<String, Object>) decision);

// evaluate the decision table with the input variables
DmnDecisionTableResult result = dmnEngine.evaluateDecisionTable(decision, variables);

int size = result.size();
DmnDecisionRuleResult ruleResult = result.get(0);
```

Comment: The actual camunda bpm version ist 7.6.0. Why do you add de.odysseus.juel?

Comment: I added the because of this post : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/camunda-bpm-users/de$2Fodysseus$2Fel$2Futil$2FSimpleContext%7Csort:relevance/camunda-bpm-users/Z2bKes3nIA0/64e24b8FCgAJ

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Comment: sorry, here it is : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/camunda-bpm-users/Z2bKes3nIA0

Answer (score 2):

Remove all your dependencies and add only `compile group: 'org.camunda.bpm.dmn', name: 'camunda-engine-dmn', version: '7.6.0'`

You can try also [menskis](https://github.com/menski/decision-starter) example, but change the camunda-engine-dmn to 7.6.0
and

```
DmnDecisionTableResult results = dmnEngine.evaluateDecisionTable("decision", "Example.dmn", variables);
```

to

```
    InputStream fileAsStream = IoUtil.fileAsStream("Example.dmn");
    DmnDecisionTableResult results = dmnEngine.evaluateDecisionTable("decision", fileAsStream, variables);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate service for decision evaluation based on key or Id,

eg:-

public void execute(DelegateExecution delegateExecution) throws Exception{
DecisionService decisionService = delegateExecution.getProcessEngineServices().getDecisionService();
decisionService.evaluateDecisionByKey(dmnToInvoke).variables(delegateExecution.get Variables()).evaluate();
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).